# MySQL, Join two tables with one table?

Tags: mysql

I have one table `customer`, and one `bill`, and one `sell`.

**Customer table**

```
id-----name
```

**Bill table**

```
id-----customer_id
```

**Sell table**

```
id-----customer_id-----bill_id-----qtt-----price
```

A customer can have the records in the `sell` table with `customer_id`, and also have the `bill` record in the `bill` table with `customer_id` and this `bill` record has record in the `sell` table with `bill_id`.
This means a customer can have direct or indirect (in this case by passing the `bill` table) with `sell` table.

Now how to join tables that retrieve the total sell of a customer with ascending or deciding order?

Any idea?

I have tried many ways for example something like below, but none of them was working:

```
SELECT 
    sell.id AS sell_id,
    customer.id,
    bill.id AS bill_id,
    customer.`name`,
    sell.quantity*sell.price AS sell_price
FROM
    customer_tb customer
    JOIN bill ON bill.customer_id = customer.id
    JOIN sell ON sell.customer_id = customer.id OR sell.bill_id = bill.id
```

NOTE: In case of `bill` table has a record in the `sell` table, the `customer_id` column is `NULL` and also same for the customer `sell` record the `bill_id` is `NULL`, this means in the `sell` table in the same entry only one of the (`customer_id`, `bill_id`) column has value.

Comment: You ask good questions. But, with respect, it's difficult to understand you. Would you consider asking a colleague with better English to help you?

Answer (score 0):

You have the customer column in your sell tables, you don't need to join with bill table.

```
SELECT 
   customer.id,
   customer.name,
   SUM(sell.quantity * sell.price) AS total_amount
FROM customer_tb as customer
INNER JOIN sell 
   On sell.customer_id = customer.id
GROUP BY customer.id
```

You have to group your rows by the customer to get their sum independently

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question, the columns custumer_id and bill_id in the same row only one of them has value, so the customer has direct and indirect (by bill table) relation with sell.

Answer (score 0):

Your challenge is to look up the correct Customer.name for each Sell row.

You need to join Sell to Customer, and also join Sell to Bill to Customer.

How to do this?

```
        FROM Sell s
   LEFT JOIN Cust c1 ON s.customer_id = c1.id
   LEFT JOIN Bill b on s.bill_id = b.id
   LEFT JOIN Cust c2 ON b.customer_id = c2.id
```

That gives us:

- s.id:  the Sale id
- s.quantity, s.price: the business details of the Sale
- c1.name: the Customer name directly from the Sale's customer_id
- c2.name: the Customer name indirectly through the Sale's bill_id

Because we use LEFT JOINs, either name can be NULL depending on which ids are null. And, I believe you favor using the direct name over the indirect name if you have both.

That means we use [COALESCE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to choose one name from the two. Something like this

```
      SELECT s.id, s.Quantity, s.Price,
             COALESCE (c1.name, c2.name) name,
             COALESCE (c1.id, c2.id) customer_id
        FROM Sell s
   LEFT JOIN Cust c1 ON s.customer_id = c1.id
   LEFT JOIN Bill b on s.bill_id = b.id
   LEFT JOIN Cust c2 ON b.customer_id = c2.id
```

But, if you have a chance to rework this database before you put a ton of data into it, please consider redesigning things to get rid of this ambiguity. It's going to drive you mad and cost you bigger servers if you have to make it work well with megarows.

Comment: Hmmm, I tried what you mentioned, but still has problem.  It seems just easy, get rows from the sell table, which has the customer _id or has the bill_id which this user is related to this bill row. Namely, the customer has direct and indirect relations with sell, indirect is by passing the bill table.  Seems easy, but hard to do. Anyway, thanks for the reply!!